# 2 Chaves estrangeiras em uma mesma chave

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados

boa tarde! Estou fazendo um exercício de Banco de Dados e me deparei com um problema. Estou cadastrando um BD de uma empresa aérea. Em uma das tabelas chamada voo preciso cadastrar o codigo de um aeroporto de origem e outro codigo de um aeroporto de destino.

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  voo (
num_voo NUMERIC(3) NOT NULL,
cod_aeroporto_origem VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
cod_aeroporto_destino VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
vlr_distancia NUMERIC(6) NOT NULL,
vlr_preco NUMERIC(6,2) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT pk_voo
 PRIMARY KEY(num_voo),

 CONSTRAINT fk_voo_aeroporto
 FOREIGN KEY(cod_aeroporto_origem, cod_aeroporto_destino)
 REFERENCES aeroporto(cod_aeroporto)


 ON DELETE RESTRICT
ON UPDATE RESTRICT
) engine="innodb";

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  aeroporto (
cod_aeroporto VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
nom_aeroporto VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
nom_cidade VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT pk_aeroporto
 PRIMARY KEY(cod_aeroporto)

ON DELETE RESTRICT
ON UPDATE RESTRICT

) engine="innodb";
```

Porém ao colocar no banco de dados, foi me dado o seguinte erro: Definição errada da chave estrangeira para 'fk_voo_aeroporto': Referência da chave e referência da tabela não coincidem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparentemente o erro foi resolvido, usei uma Constraint só para as duas FK

```
CONSTRAINT fk_voo_aeroporto
 FOREIGN KEY(cod_aeroporto_origem)
 REFERENCES aeroporto(cod_aeroporto),
 FOREIGN KEY(cod_aeroporto_destino)
 REFERENCES aeroporto(cod_aeroporto)
```

Answer (score 2):

Você está referenciando apenas um campo e a foreign key tem 2 campos, não sei se isso vai funcionar mas tenta criar duas fks, uma pro destino e outra pra chegada

```
     CONSTRAINT fk_voo_aeroporto_origem
         FOREIGN KEY(cod_aeroporto_origem)
         REFERENCES aeroporto(cod_aeroporto),

 CONSTRAINT fk_voo_aeroporto_destino
     FOREIGN KEY( cod_aeroporto_destino)
     REFERENCES aeroporto(cod_aeroporto)
```

> 2 Chaves estrangeiras em uma mesma chave

Na verdade você estava criando uma chave só, composta por dois campos, e não duas chaves

Comment: Tentei criar duas fks e dá erro também. Nome da chave 'fk_voo_aeroporto' duplicado

Comment: as fks tem que ter nomes diferentes, não se pode criar duas FK's com mesmo nome